# IE9 not supporting Javascript function: show div on textarea input?

Tags: javascript

I am struggling to ge my javascript code to work in IE9. 
i need a way to show a div only when a user types into a textarea field.
but currently it wont work at all in IE9 and i need it to work in this browser, can someone please show me what im doing wrong.

here is my html:

```
<input type="text" id="cname" name="cname" class="field">
<div id="cname2">cname2</div>
```

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#cname").on('input', function() {
       $('#cname2')[this.value.length > 8 ? 'hide' : 'show']('slow');
   });
});
```

css:

```
#cname2{
display:none;
}
```

Comment: Please define _"it wont work at all"_

Comment: Cannot reproduce http://jsfiddle.net/YMxa9/ (IE11 emulating IE9)

Comment: I suggest you to not use the input event; Try input/textarea element and change/keyup event listeners. It just works.

Also - read the article https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/input , especially the "Browser compatibility" section.